# How can I differentiate tan(x) to sec^2(x) instead of tan^2(x) + 1 in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

When differentiating `tan(x)` in Sympy, it returns the answer as `tan^2(x) + 1`. However I was wondering if their is any way to convert `tan^2(x) + 1` to `sec^2(x)` in Sympy. I've tried using `trigsimp()` but it simplifies it to `1/cos^2(x)` and not `sec^2(x)`.

Comment: what have you tried so far please ?

Comment: I've tried using both the simplify() and trigsimp() but none of them converted it into sec^2(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fu.py module contains many transforms as described by Fu, et al. For your case TR22 will be of use:

```
>>> from sympy.simplify.fu import TR22
>>> from sympy import tan
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> TR22( tan(x)**2+1 )
sec(x)**2
```

Comment: See also the [source code on github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/simplify/fu.py) (with additional explication) and [these docs](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/simplify/fu.html)